# Can I get response time using RestSharp?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'd like to calculate time response using RestSharp, but actually I'm using stopwatch func to execute my target. Is there some other way  using restSharp functions to get time response? Or this one is the best choice?

```
public class LoadingTimes
{
    public Stopwatch Stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

    public List<double> GetResponsesTimesForSelectedPage(PageInformation pageInformation)
    {
        var responsesTimesList = new List<double>();
        var client = new RestClient(pageInformation.Url);
        var request = new RestRequest("/City/berlijn/", Method.GET);

        for (int actualExecution = 1; actualExecution <= pageInformation.ExecutionsCount; actualExecution++)
        {
            Stopwatch.Start();
            client.Execute(request);
            Stopwatch.Stop();
            responsesTimesList.Add(Stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
            Stopwatch.Reset();
        }
        return responsesTimesList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, rather my question was like confirmation - if that's why is correct. Or rather not

Comment: Requests are mostly timed on servers. Client timing makes little sense because it is not clear what are you measuring - the network or the server.